# "They encamped at Makelot" Bamidbar 33:25

Tags: bamidbar-numbers-book-of, masei, tur

The [verse 25 of chapter 33](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.33.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) in Sefer Bamidbar tells us the Bnei Israel encamped at Makelot.
The [Baal Haturim](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.33.25?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Kitzur_Baal_Haturim_on_Numbers.33.25&lang2=bi) comments on this verse: **במקהלות:** *ע''ש ויקהלו על משה ועל אהרן*.

What is the exact source of this verse quoted here by the Baal Haturim since it can be found [in parashat Korach](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.3?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0) and [in parashat Chukat](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.20.2?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)?

Comment: It would be helpful for investigating context if you could edit in citations and preferably also links for the two verses alluded to in Korach and Chukat.

Comment: Perhaps that's why it's plural במקהלות rather than במקהלה(?)

Comment: @Loewian, I see what you're trying to say. But I feel like the Baal Haturim tries to identify the stations by linking them to previous known events that occurred previously in the desert. In this context, Baal Haturim claims that Korach rebellion took place in Kehelat (Bamidbar 33:22). So I would argue that Makelot is a station we could find in parshat Chukat, and it would make sense that ויקהלו על משה ועל אהרן quote was taken from Chukat and not Korach.